# sum of bytes with sum()

Tags: python, byte

Why does the following code lead to a `TypeError` ?

```
a = b'\x01'
b = b'\x02'
_tuple = (a, b)
sum(_tuple)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'bytes'
```

While a and b are both bytes (quickly checked with `type(a)`

Comment: you need to define an initial value, or just do sum(*_tuple)

Comment: `sum(_tuple, start=b'\0')`

Comment: Internally, `sum()` initializes the sum to integer 0.  Then you get the type error when it tries to add a byte value.

Comment: @Barmar that doesn't work (at least in 3.9), as it raises a `TypeError`.

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Are you trying to sum the byte values or concatenate the byte strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like the error for `sum(_tuple, b'\0')` says:

you need to use `b''.join(_tuple)` instead.

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sum() can't sum bytes [use b''.join(seq) instead]
```

EDIT:
allow the actual requested calculation to be done.

helper function:

```
def split_int(num, split):
    """convert base-10 int to other bases and return digits in a list"""
    res = []
    exp = 1
    while exp < num:
        trunc = exp
        exp *= split
        current_num = num % exp // trunc
        res.insert(0, current_num)
    return res
```

at first you need to convert bytes to int:

```
def sum_bytes(*bytes):
    """sum bytes"""
    int_list = [int.from_bytes(byte, 'big') for byte in bytes]
    # use 'little' if the smallest byte comes first.
```

then you need to sum the integers:

```
    int_sum = sum(int_list)
```

finally you need to reconvert these into bytes. it the result is > 256 you need the above helper function:

```
    byte_sum = bytes(split_int(int_sum, 256))
    return byte_sum
```

a more compressed code would be:

```
def split_int(num, split):
    """convert base-10 int to other bases and return digits in a list"""
    res = []
    exp = 1
    while exp < num:
        trunc = exp
        exp *= split
        current_num = num % exp // trunc
        res.insert(0, current_num)
    return res

def sum_bytes(*bytes):
    """sum bytes"""
    int_sum = sum((int.from_bytes(byte, 'big') for byte in bytes))
    return bytes(split_int(int_sum, 256))
```

Comment: +1, I don't think your downvote was deserved, however, I think OP hasn't yet provided enough information for this answer to be considered sufficient. It's not clear yet what OP's expected outcome is here.

Comment: He might be trying to get `b'\x03'`

Comment: @Barmar I researched this and finally provided code for this.

Comment: Tested the reconversion to bytes for different integers and compared with `int_sum.to_bytes(2, 'big')` (in my case, a length of 2 bytes is desired). With 255 and `split_int()`: `b'\xff'`, with 255 and `to_bytes()`: `b'\x00\xff'`, which is OK. But with 256 and `split_int()`, the result seems wrong: `b'\x00'` (zero), whereas with 256 and `to_bytes()`, it's correct: `b'\x01\x00'`. It works again with 257, though (both methods return `b'\x01\x01'`). So, I suppose using `int_sum.to_bytes(2, 'big')` is the more robust approach.